# How to disable gestures in Xamarin on iOS?

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin

I want to disable back swipe gestures only on one page (because they conflict with UrhoSharp scene), but I don't want to use modal page. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding this code

```
if (Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage is MasterDetailPage masterDetailPage)
{
    masterDetailPage.IsGestureEnabled = false;
}

else if (Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage is NavigationPage navigationPage && navigationPage.CurrentPage is MasterDetailPage nestedMasterDetail)
{
   nestedMasterDetail.IsGestureEnabled = false;
}
```